# Diagonalizing 2x2 Matrix and Finding Eigenvalues of 2x2 Matrix yields different results in Wolfram. Why?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, wolfram-alpha

I want to find the eigenvalues of the matrix, $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & cos(k)+sin(k) \\
    cos(k)+sin(k) & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}.$$

With diagonalize {{0,  cos(k)+sin(k)}, {cos(k)+sin(k), 0}}
I get the two eigenvalues: $$\pm\sqrt{sin(2k)+1}$$
With eigenvalues {{0,  cos(k)+sin(k)}, {cos(k)+sin(k), 0}} I get:
$$\pm(cos(k)+sin(k))$$
Why do I get different results?

Comment: Is there a discrepancy with the eigenvalues or eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, if you plot both functions, say with wolfram alpha, then you will see that they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\pm \sqrt{\sin(2k) + 1} = \pm \sqrt{(\sin(k) + \cos(k))^2} = \pm (\sin(k) + \cos(k))$$

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are correct. For each real number *k*, the number $\sin(2k)+1$ is non-negative; therefore, it has $2$ square roots. Note that$$\bigl(\cos(k)+\sin(k)\bigr)^2=1+2\sin(k)\cos(k)=1+\sin(2k).$$Therefore, the square roots of $\sin(2k)+1$ are $\pm\bigl(\cos(k)+\sin(k)\bigr)$.